# select statement stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I have three tables in database:

```
user_tbl: userID | name | email | password
task_tbl: taskID | description | Date
usertask_tbl: userID | taskID
```

Now i want to display all the tasks related to one user, it should go and get check the taskid of that user and show all the description and date for that user. But instead its showing one description and date.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `alltask`(IN `useremail` INT(11))
BEGIN
SELECT @userID := userID FROM user_tbl WHERE email=useremail;
SELECT @TaskID :=taskID from usertask_tbl WHERE userID = @userID;
SELECT description, Date from task_tbl WHERE taskID = @TaskID;
END
```

I'm new to this. If this is not the right way to do it please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting one task when you do:

```
SELECT @TaskID :=taskID from usertask_tbl WHERE userID = @userID;
```

Therefore, instead of:

```
SELECT @TaskID :=taskID from usertask_tbl WHERE userID = @userID;
SELECT description, Date from task_tbl WHERE taskID = @TaskID;
```

Try:

```
SELECT description, Date from task_tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN usertask_tbl AS t2 ON t1.taskID = t2.taskID
WHERE userID = @userID;
```